# How use progress bar for a project that it's calculations is in another project

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have two project: a class library and a winform and all of the calculations is in the class library. now I want to use a progress bar for one of my forms when the user click on Run botton. I tried the below code but the progress bar filled as soon as loading data (about 6000 or more) in datagridview.

Code in Winform project:

```
private void BtnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = TTools.Depth.Count;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        foreach (double doub in TLitho.CalcPercent().Item3)
        {
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }

        if (TTools.Depth != null)
        {
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            List<double> DolomitePer = TLitho.CalcPercent().Item3;
            List<double> Depth = TTools.Depth;

            var sourceD = new BindingSource
            {
                DataSource = Depth
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < (sourceD.Count); i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = sourceD[i];
            }
            var sourcePD = new BindingSource
            {
                DataSource = DolomitePer
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < (sourcePD.Count); i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = sourcePD[i];

            }
        }
    }
```

code in class library project:

```
public static Tuple<List<double>, List<double>, List<double>> CalcPercent()
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < TTools.Depth.Count; j++)
        {

            MinimumIndexQC.Add(80000);
            MinimumIndexQC[j] = lQC[j].IndexOf(lQC[j].Min());
            MinimumIndexCD.Add(80000);
            MinimumIndexCD[j] = lCD[j].IndexOf(lCD[j].Min());
            MinimumIndexQD.Add(80000);
            MinimumIndexQD[j] = lQD[j].IndexOf(lQD[j].Min());

            CDandND.Add(Math.Abs(lCD[j][MinimumIndexCD[j]] - TPorosity.CalculateNDPorosity()[j]));
            QCandND.Add(Math.Abs(lQC[j][MinimumIndexQC[j]] - TPorosity.CalculateNDPorosity()[j]));
            QDandND.Add(Math.Abs(lQD[j][MinimumIndexQD[j]] - TPorosity.CalculateNDPorosity()[j]));
            if (CDandND[j] < QCandND[j] && CDandND[j] < QDandND[j])
            {
                DistanceCD.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.9162) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1))
                    + (Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.7031) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)));
                DolomitePercent.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.7031) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)) / DistanceCD[j]);
                CalcitePercent.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.9162) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)) / DistanceCD[j]);
                QuartzPercent.Add(0);
                DistanceQC.Add(0);
                DistanceQD.Add(0);
            }
            else if (QCandND[j] < CDandND[j] && QCandND[j] < QDandND[j])
            {
                DistanceQC.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0192 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.5818) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0192, 2) + 1))
                    + (Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.7031) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)));
                QuartzPercent.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.7031) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)) / DistanceQC[j]);
                CalcitePercent.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0192 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.5818) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0192, 2) + 1)) / DistanceQC[j]);
                DolomitePercent.Add(0);
                DistanceCD.Add(0);
                DistanceQD.Add(0);

            }
            else if (QDandND[j] < CDandND[j] && QDandND[j] < QCandND[j])
            {
                DistanceQD.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0192 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.5818) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0192, 2) + 1))
                   + (Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.9162) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)));
                QuartzPercent.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.9162) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0173, 2) + 1)) / DistanceQD[j]);
                DolomitePercent.Add((Math.Abs(TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] + (0.0192 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) - 2.5818) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(0.0192, 2) + 1)) / DistanceQD[j]);
                CalcitePercent.Add(0);
                DistanceCD.Add(0);
                DistanceQC.Add(0);
            }
            else
            {
                DistanceCD.Add(0);
                DistanceQC.Add(0);
                DistanceQD.Add(0);
                DolomitePercent.Add(0);
                CalcitePercent.Add(0);
                QuartzPercent.Add(0);
            }
            if (DolomitePercent[j]==0 && CalcitePercent[j]==0 && QuartzPercent[j]==0 && TPorosity.BulkDensity[j] < (-0.0173 * TPorosity.Neutron[j]) + 2.9162)
            {
                DolomitePercent[j] = 100;
            }
            if (DolomitePercent[j] == 0 && CalcitePercent[j] == 0 && QuartzPercent[j] == 0 && TPorosity.BulkDensity[j]> 2.5943 * Math.Pow(Math.E, (-0.009 * TPorosity.Neutron[j])))
            {
                QuartzPercent[j] = 100;
            }

          }
        return Tuple.Create(DolomitePercent, CalcitePercent, QuartzPercent);
       }
   }
```

Hope anyone help me.
thank you

Comment: A consideration: the `CalcPercent()` appears to only do some math. How long does it take? You said it returns 6000+ *elements*. Do you really need a ProgressBar? It would just slow down the whole procedure. Maybe use a marquee or another graphic element that simulates a waiting phase. Then, what are those BindingSource(s) for? You seem to fill the DataGridView a cell at the time. Why don't you set the DataSource of the DGV directly? That's what a BindingSource is for. Is it just to try and perform the least important task, the *progress* thing?

Comment: Thanks Jimi! the user should wait about 15min for The Calculations and filling datagridview. I thing really need a ProgessBar when the user in waiting.

Comment: Just question pardon me. Are you doing all that in the main thread? I'm asking because I can't see otherwise in your code.

Comment: I'ld start to optimize this procedure. As of now, it looks like you're using just one of the `List<double>`: `TLitho.CalcPercent().Item3`. Also, you are doing the calculation twice, calling `TLitho.CalcPercent().Item3` twice. See how much it takes to perform this step, optimizing your current code. Just the math and return values, without the UI stuff. A progress bar is not better than a graphic *symbolic awaiter* when one already knows how much, more or less, it's going to take to finish. The importat thing is that the app doesn't appear (or *feel*) stuck.

Comment: It's possible to perform a visual Progress here (raising events when chunks of data are processed, for example). But it's something that may take away more than it adds in quality. Much depends on the *presentation* (how an user may *feel* about it)

Comment: Thanks JQSOFT! I bring some of my code in question. in real my datagridview has 4 columns and I use Iterm 1 and 2, and also the calculations is more than this. Thanks a lot Jimi!

Comment: zahra Most welcome. I don't know if you've managed to solve the problem or not. Anyways, consider carefully the comments of @Jimi since you have much important things to solve before the progress thing. If you insist to use the progress bar though, just let us know. Good luck.

Comment: sure JQSOFT, thank you so much